# DSolve does not return solution to simple system of second order PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I'm trying to solve a simple system of second order PDEs with Mathematica 11.1.
Here is the system:

```
DSolve[{
  D[f[x, y, z], x, y] == 0,
  D[f[x, y, z], x, z] == 0,
  D[f[x, y, z], y, z] == 0
  }, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

Mathematica returns it unevaluated...
I expect the solution to be

```
f[x,y,z] -> C[1][x] + C[2][y] + C[3][z]
```

Any idea what I can try?

Thanks!

**Update:**

We can differentiate a third time:

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y, z], x, y, z] == 0}, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

and then Mathematica gives the following answer:

```
f[x, y, z] -> C[1][y, z] + C[2][x, z] + C[3][x, y]
```

Maybe this can be somehow combined with the answer by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey) to give the correct answer for the system above?

Comment: Trying to solve the simpler `DSolve[{D[f[x, y, z], x, y] == 0, D[f[x, y, z], x, z] == 0}, 
 f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]` leaks an internal error and returns a manifestly wrong answer, `{{f[x, y, z] -> C[1][y, z] + Inactive[Integrate][C[1][K[2]], {K[2], 1, x}]}}`.

Comment: This nonstandard system is not so simple since Maple produces a non-optimal answer $$ f \left( x,y,z \right) ={\it \_F6} \left( x \right) +{\it \_F5}
 \left( z \right) +{\it \_F4} \left( y \right) +{\it \_F3} \left( z
 \right).
$$

Comment: The error described in my earlier comment above has been fixed in Version 12.3.1..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by user64494 suggested to me the following

```
sxy = Flatten@DSolve[{D[f[x, y, z], x, y] == 0}, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] /. 
    C[n_][z][v_] -> d[n][v, z];
sxz = Flatten@DSolve[{D[d[1][x, z], x, z] == 0}, d[1][x, z], {x, z}] /. C -> c;
syz = Flatten@DSolve[{D[d[2][y, z], y, z] == 0}, d[2][y, z], {y, z}] /. C -> b;
sxy /. sxz /. syz
(* {f[x, y, z] -> b[1][y] + b[2][z] + c[1][x] + c[2][z]} *)
```

Not at all satisfying but perhaps useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

First we solve the system:

```
s = Flatten @@ 
   DSolve[{D[f[x, y, z], x, y, z] == 0}, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] /. 
  C[n_][a_, b_] -> d[n][a, b]
```

getting:

```
{f[x, y, z] -> d[1][y, z] + d[2][x, z] + d[3][x, y]}
```

Then we solve the original system equation for equation:

```
sxyz = Join[
  Flatten @@ 
    DSolve[D[d[1][y, z] + d[2][x, z] + d[3][x, y], x, y] == 0, 
     d[3][x, y], {x, y}] /. C[n_][a_] -> f1[n][a],
  Flatten @@ 
    DSolve[D[d[1][y, z] + d[2][x, z] + d[3][x, y], x, z] == 0, 
     d[2][x, z], {x, z}] /. C[n_][a_] -> f2[n][a],
  Flatten @@ 
    DSolve[D[d[1][y, z] + d[2][x, z] + d[3][x, y], y, z] == 0, 
     d[1][y, z], {y, z}] /. C[n_][a_] -> f3[n][a]
  ]
```

getting:

```
{d[3][x, y] -> f1[1][x] + f1[2][y], 
 d[2][x, z] -> f2[1][x] + f2[2][z],
 d[1][y, z] -> f3[1][y] + f3[2][z]}
```

The final solution comes then from:

```
(s /. sxyz) //. f_[n_][a_] + g_[m_][a_] -> F[n][m][a]
```

as:

```
{f[x, y, z] -> F[1][1][x] + F[2][1][y] + F[2][2][z]}
```